# Не корректно выполняется код

Tags: node.js

нужна помощь с модулем, пишу модуль для обработки поиска других участников в локальной сети, и проблема в том, что скрипт выполняет код сначала после цикла судя по всему а потом уже сам код который в цикле, просьба простить за корявое описани проблемы, если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.
Код :

```js
const { getIPRange } = require('get-ip-range');
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');
const data = fs.readFileSync("../conf/config.json", "utf8");
const config = JSON.parse(data);
const array = getIPRange(config.network_configuration.network);

const available_nodes = Array();
for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {

    const client = net.connect({port: 14050, hostname: array[x]});
    
        client.write("ver");
    
        client.on("data", (data) => {
            if (data.toString().includes("FreeP2P v") == true) {
                console.log("nice"); // Debug message (Выполняется после цикла почему-то.)
                available_nodes.push(array[x]);
                client.end();
            }
        });
    
        client.on("error", (err) => {});
        if (x != array.length - 1){
            break;
        }
        x++;
}
console.log(available_nodes);
```

Файл конфигурации из кода:

```json
{
    "network_configuration":
    {
        "network":"192.168.0.1/24"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Пометка : Не совсем модуль, а часть программы, т.е этот файлик лежит в папке scripts, а основной файл исполняет весь код отсюда воркером.

Comment: Обычно в вашем случае отсылают сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/ Если что-то будет неясно и захотите разобраться в теме асинхронности основательно, стоит прочитать этот раздел: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { getIPRange } = require('get-ip-range');
const net = require('net');

(async () => {
  const ipAddresses = getIPRange('192.168.0.1/24');
  const res = await Promise.allSettled(
    ipAddresses.map((ip) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const socket = net.connect(
          { port: 14050, host: ip, timeout: 5 * 1000 },
          () => {
            socket.once('data', (chunk) => {
              resolve(
                chunk.toString('utf-8').includes('FreeP2P v')
              );
              socket.destroy();
            });
            socket.write('ver');
          }
        );

        socket.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        socket.on('timeout', () => {
          reject(new Error('TIMED_OUT'));
          socket.destroy();
        });
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    })),
  );

  const availableNodes = res.reduce(
    (acc, x, idx) => {
      if (x.status === 'fulfilled' && x.value === true) {
        acc.push(ipAddresses[idx]);
      }
      return acc;
    },
    [],
  );

  console.log('availableNodes', availableNodes);
})();
```

Comment: решение умозрительное так как в моей сети таких зверей нет

Comment: Потестирую, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо больше! Работает идеально, можете подсказать, что было в моём коде не так и что вы сделали? Что бы я хоть что то понял

Comment: `что было в моём коде не так и что вы сделали`, увы, в вашем коде было не так всё. написанная вами программа написана для какого-то синхронного движка (или языка типа python/perl), но не для nodejs. пояснение [асинхронного] подхода, на котором основана работа nodejs, займёт пару часов и вряд ли поместится в формат комментария. так что для самостоятельного изучения:

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-loop

Comment: https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/net.html

Comment: Спасибо большое.